# Change of variable formula for the image of a hypercube

Tags: integration, measure-theory, alternative-proof

Let $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an injective $C^1$ map. Let $I=[0, 1]^n$. I want to show that $$m(\varphi(I))=\int_I \left|\det D\varphi(x)\right|dx.$$
This is a special case of the change of variable formula, but I think there is a simpler proof in this case (that I still can't find). Maybe one can compute $m(\varphi([0, \varepsilon]^n))$, with small $\varepsilon$, reducing to the one dimensional case and using Fubini.

What do you think?

Comment: First, I think you want to assume that $\varphi$ is injective. I suspect that the proof in this case is not much easier than for the general case. In fact, once you have this case, you have the formula for simple functions, after which it follows for general functions easily by density. There is a much simpler proof if you assume that $\varphi$ is the identity outside of some ball: see P.D. Lax's beautiful American Mathematical Monthly article "Change of Variables in Multiple Integrals", and the followup "Change of Variables in Multiple Integrals II" for the general case.

Comment: @AbrahamFrei-Pearson: could you give more details on: "once you have this case, you have the formula for simple functions, after which it follows for general functions easily by density" ? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Let $f$ be a step function. Write $f = \sum_k a_k 1_{I_k}$, where $I_k$ is a cube. By linearity, the change of variables formula holds for $f$.  Since every open set can be written as the countable union of cubes with disjoint interiors, the change of variables formula follows when $f$ is the characteristic function of an open set from the monotone convergence theorem. Since every measurable set can be approximated by an open set, the formula follows when $f$ is the characteristic function of any bounded measurable set. By linearity, the formula holds for simple functions with

Comment: compact support. Since every positive, $L^1$ function with compact support can be approximated from below by simple functions with compact support, the formula follows for such functions by the monotone convergence theorem. It then follows for arbitrary $L^1$ functions with compact support by considering positive and negative parts. The change of variables formula is usually stated as $\int f \circ \phi = \int f Det(D \phi)$ when $f$ is a continuous function with compact support. For functions with unbounded support, you may (or may not, I'm not sure) need to impose some kind of condition

Comment: on $\phi$ to ensure that something doesn't go wrong with the integrability of $f \circ \phi$. In any case, when $f$ is continuous with compact support, its positive part can be approximated from below by step functions.

Comment: @AbrahamFrei-Pearson: thanks! But actually I was interested in the Riemann integral case.

Comment: @AbrahamFrei-Pearson: if you answer the question showing that (for Riemann integrals) this case implies easily the general case, I can give you the bounty, because that would 'show' that it's hard to find an easier proof.

Comment: @user72870: Can you prove it for linear maps? It's a start.

Comment: @orangeskid: yes!

Answer (score 0):

If $\varphi$ is $C^1$ and injective (not quite enough, since the derivative may be 0, otherwise the measure falls apart. You need $\varphi$ to be a diffeomorphism). We want to compute
$$ m(\varphi(I)) =\int_{\varphi(I)} dy $$
Since $\varphi$ is $C^1$ and injective, we have the inverse function theorem. I.e. we have $\varphi^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Thus it makes sense to consider $x = \varphi^{-1}(y)$. Since everything matches in one-to-one correspondence, we know that $\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(I))=I$, which means
$$m(\varphi(I)) =\int_{\varphi(I)} dy = \int_{I} d ( \varphi(x)) $$
Now we just have to understand what $d ( \varphi(x))$ means. This is the statement of the change of variables formula...i.e. we see this isn't any simpler to prove. In fact, it's the same proof since if you show if for a small cube, you can always build up more complicated regions in cubes. In term of differential forms we have
$$ dy = dy_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dy_n 
\to d ( \varphi(x)) =d \varphi_1(x) \wedge \ldots d \varphi_n (x) = (\partial_{x_1}\varphi_1 dx_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \partial _{x_n} \varphi_1  dx_n) \wedge \ldots \wedge((\partial_{x_1}\varphi_n dx_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \partial _{x_n} \varphi_n  dx_n)$$
which works out to $|\det D \varphi | dx_1 \wedge \ldots dx_n = |\det D \varphi | dx$ when all is said and done. Otherwise you'll have to go by the the definition you're comfortable with.

Comment: What if you assume that $\phi^{-1}$ is also $C^{1}$? That would make it simpler a bit.

Comment: That is enough, but that is the assumption in the usual proof